# Largest Number Datatype MPI

Tags: c, types, numbers, mpi, factorial

What is the largest C number datatype MPI supports?
Is there some way to use `intmax_t`?

I want to calculate the factorial, but I can't get over 170!.

Comment: @Thomas: according to [a relevant `man` page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mpi_double), `MPI_DOUBLE` already maps to C's native `double` (which is what OP is currently using). `MPI_LONG_DOUBLE` could be a suggestion (it allows values as large as 1.18×10⁴⁹³²`) but that same man page warns "some systems may not implement".

Answer (score 3):

The largest primitive integer data type would be an `MPI_UINT64_T` which would get you up to 2^64 - 1

For larger integers you would have to use a library such as [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) which supports arbitary precision arithmatic. You would then have to set up an MPI derived data type to use them with MPI though.

Comment: 170! is 307 digits long, which suggests OP is currently using a `double` (to be exact: "IEEE 754 double-precision binary floating-point format"), and not especially interested in (1) integers, and (2) an exact result . 2^64 is only 19-and-a-bit digits. So this needs a custom number type anyway.

Comment: @Jongware That's right, currently I'm using double. I tried `MPI_LONG_DOUBLE` yesterday. As you suggests in the other comment, this offers great range. The disadvantage is the precision - only the first 18 digits are accurate.